# C opendir by Hostname

Tags: c, opendir

I try to open a shared directory to an other computer.
Here is the code that I used.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
    DIR * rep = NULL;

    rep = opendir("\\\\MYCOMPUTER");
    if(rep==NULL)
        perror("");
    else{
        printf("enfin !");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I got the error that there is no directory of file.
When I try to open my direct by my explorer it's work fine. I open it using \\MYCOMPUTER.

Do you have an idea ?

thank you :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Which operating system do you use ?

Comment: Thank you Rubber Boots but my program is in C and not in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [UNC syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) here. I can't test it right now, but I *assume* that ... because all *UNC* paths are defined of being of the form:

```
\\host\shared_folder\resource
```

A simple

```
\\host
```

does not qualify as a *directory*. The code would probably work for

```
\\host\shared_folder
```

So, if you want to enumerate all *shared folders* on a windows network server, you probably have to resort to the [native win32 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525387(v=vs.85).aspx)